# Arch - How do Install a package made in a clean chroot?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, chroot

I've been trying to build and install GNU Icecat from source on Arch linux using `yaourt`, but I've recieved errors during the build relating to the Infinality font set.

I came across [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DeveloperWiki:Building_in_a_Clean_Chroot) page from the arch wiki which suggested that I could build the package in a clean chroot using the `devtools` package, which I have successfully done using the `extra-x86_64-build` build script.

However, what the page is missing is any info on how to install the package to my main root from there. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If the build was successful, once it is completed, there will be a foo.pkg.tar.xz in the build directory and you can use pacman to install the built package:

```
sudo pacman -U foo.pkg.tar.xz
```

Comment: It completed the build to the best of my knowledge, and under /build/icecat/ are two folders, /src/ and /pkg/. /src/ contains the source files, but /pkg/ contains /icecat/usr/ with a /bin/, /lib/ and /share/, but no tar files anywhere. Do I need to compress it myself?

Comment: @user135925 The directory where the PKGBUILD is (where you ran: `sudo makechrootpkg -c -r $CHROOT`) should contain the built package. Please edit your question to include the *exact* steps you followed.